# Got an 404 error to get favicon with <%= BASE_URL %>

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, syntax-highlighting, favicon

I've got some questions about the `BASE_URL` in a standard vue.js project.

1. My IDE (vs code) shows me this red marked `<` icon in the `index.html` and I don't know why:

[image]

if I hover over the red element it says only: `[Follow link](file:///c:/Users/.../public/<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico)`

2. In the Browser I got this `404` error message

[image]

if I want to `serve` my application I got this error message:

[image]

---

Do you have any idea how to fix the error?

---

#### Update:

The console error `'parseComponent' of undefined` comes from a different version between vue.js with `v2.6.10` & vue-template-compiler `v2.5.X`. They must be the same to run the app.

Comment: Don't know if this is the reason but I noticed that your project is served to port 8080, but the BASE_URL is defined as 8000.

Comment: you are right. I use vue.js in a project as a module, so I have two development environments running. Do you know why my IDE marks the icon `<` in red for me?

Comment: Do you have an Vue.JS extension for VS Code? I personally use "Vetur".

Comment: I use ESLint and Vetur. Besides that, I have very few extensions installed.